# Host a nodejs and socketio app on a dedicated hosting (EC2)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a private messaging app built with nodejs and socketio which works in the url `http://localhost:3000`

I'm wondering how would I integrate it in a dedicated server like Amazon's EC2? I can understand that it will work on `http://someip:3000` but I want the chat application to work inside a website, just like facebook. How do I set it up to work on all website pages?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a web server to proxy your app in the port 80 (http), this is a basic configuration for Nginx where the node app running in 127.0.0.1:3000 will be proxied to the port 80 of www.example.com that should point to the EC2 public IP:

```
upstream node {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {  
  server_name www.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log warn;

  listen 80;

  location / {
    ## Socket.io
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    ## End Socket.io
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://node;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  }
}
```